# wifi problem ubuntu 16.04 on fujitsu amilo li-2727

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

I am struggling to install ubuntu 16.04 on a FS Amilo li-2727 with the wifi working.

When I install from a usb iso image of 16.04, it picks up the atheros wifi hardware but does not pick up my wifi network. The wifi led light is also not active.

Some Google searches revealed that the wifi is switched off and can only switch it on by using cltr + F1 which only works in windows vista. Tried couple of the terminal commands suggested on searches but none worked.

However, when I install from a usb iso image of 14.04.5 it picks up the atheros wifi hardware and am able to connect and use my wifi connection.
I am currently upgrading the 14.04.5 to 16.04.Hopefully this ends up with a 16.04 version of Ubuntu desktop where the wifi is working.

My question is:
Is there another way of getting the wifi to work with a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 other than installing 14.04.5 and then upgrading to 16.04?

your suggestions will be appreciated.

Regards

Rocco

Answer (score 0):

In my Li272 it helped update BIOS to ver. 1.10.
Wifi is enabled by default.

http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/content/QuicksearchResult.asp?lng=COM&q=amilo+li2727&btnG_x=11&btnG_y=12

Regards
Koralez

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the BIOS to version 1.10. But, since the last update of UBUNTU 16.04 LTS (in July 2018) the WIFI of my AMILO LI2727 doesn't work anymore, nor the video card.

After having tested different distributions (UBUNTU 18.04 LTS, XUBUNTU 18.04 LTS, reinstall of UBUNTU 16.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS) the final solution was to keep an old version of UBUNTU (14.04 LTS) and to avoid the update to a new version (I kept the other updates) and everything works perfectly.

Regards

JEB